# Remove Metadata

Tags: objective-c, metadata, cgimage

I want to remove some metadata, sometimes all metadata, of images without quality loss. I tried passing `kCFNull` and `[NSNull null]` as values in the dictionary. I also tried to delete some key/value pairs completely. However, everything I delete magically returns. This is the code I successfully use to modify values:

```
- (NSData *)dataForImageAsset:(ALAsset *)asset withMetadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    Byte *buffer = (Byte *)malloc((long)rep.size);
    NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(long)rep.size error:nil];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
    CFStringRef imageType = CGImageSourceGetType(source);

    NSMutableData *resultData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGImageDestinationRef imgDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)(resultData), imageType, 1, NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imgDest, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)metadata);
    BOOL success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDest);

    CFRelease(imgDest);
    CFRelease(source);

    if (success) {
        return resultData;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

//EDIT//

When I set the metadata to a dictionary that just contains empty strings for the keys {Exif} and {TIFF}, it raises the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f9c0'
```

That means that `CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource` does not use my metadata to overwrite the whole thing. It just overwrites the values of the existing fields. If there is no value, the existing value is not overwritten.

I could just set a meaningless value for all the fields I want to delete, but I actually don't want the keys to show up. Converting to PNG or JPEG is not an option, as I want to keep the original quality.

I had the idea to create a new ALAsset using `- (void)writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock` but the metadata problem persists.

Is there any way to strip the metadata from the raw imageData?

Comment: not sure why yet.  However whenever you call malloc you need to call free.  free(buffer);

Comment: Passing `YES` for the `freeWhenDone:` parameter of `NSData`'s `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:` means they don't have to balance the `malloc()` call with an explicit `free()` call themselves; rather, when the `imageData` variable is deallocated, it handles calling `malloc()`.